# automatically move to text next line if width of div is reach

Tags: javascript, css

I want the text to move next line if the div width is reach
This is using echo. This is inside that 
div id="chat"

```
echo '<div style="width: auto; margin-left: 400px; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 10px; padding-left:8px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 15px; text-align:left; font-size: 0.8em; color:#015E7D;">' . '<div style="font-weight:bold;">' . "You" . "</div>message: " . $messages->msg . "<br>" . '<div style="font-size: 0.6em;">' . "Send : " . $messages->dt . "</div>" . "</div>";
```

[image: Error]

@squaleLis suggesstion output
[image: error2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my assumption you want the text to come in the next line when it touches the width of the div. For this you have to use "word-wrap:break-word"

HTML

```
<div class="test">aaaa sdfjdshfjsd djhsdjs aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

CSS

```
.test{width:200px;border:1px solid blue;word-wrap:break-word;}
```

Here is a live example for you https://jsfiddle.net/Rit_Design/0L5wb62r/

Comment: thanks @RIT Design. That is exactly the right answer for my question and it fixed my problem. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I need to put a `width` (or a `max-width`) to the container div.

However text clip is the normally behavior. Maybe your css overwrite it. So I suggest you to add also the [`text-overflow`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp) and [`white-space`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) rules.

SNIPPET:

```css
div {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-overflow: clip;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div>
Quel ramo del lago di Como, che volge a mezzogiorno, tra due catene non interrotte di monti, tutto a seni e a golfi, a seconda dello sporgere e del rientrare di quelli, vien, quasi a un tratto, a ristringersi, e a prender corso e figura di fiume, tra un promontorio a destra, e un’ampia costiera dall’altra parte; e il ponte, che ivi congiunge le due rive, par che renda ancor più sensibile all’occhio questa trasformazione, e segni il punto in cui il lago cessa, e l’Adda rincomincia, per ripigliar poi nome di lago dove le rive, allontanandosi di nuovo, lascian l’acqua distendersi e rallentarsi in nuovi golfi e in nuovi seni. 
</div>
```

---

## EDIT

It was not clear to me that you want also break word (so without waiting for white space). The property you need is [`word-break`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp), set to `break-all`.

Comment: what i want is to move the text below when it hits the max-width. using ellipsis and clip i will not be able read all the text cause ellipsis outputs text.... and clip just don't let you read all when it hits the div max-width

Comment: i will update my question i will post new photo using your suggession